# Capturing packets using wireshark of an IoT device

Tags: wifi, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I have an IoT device that connects to my wifi router using wifi. There is a limitation of capturing network logs on the device itself so I thought to capture it using Wireshark.

I am using windows 10 and downloaded the latest version of Wireshark. Now that my laptop and my IoT device connect to the same network through the same router, I am not able to capture the packets in and out from my IoT device.
I put the filer as ip.addr == {ip of the IoT device). But it shows nothing.
Is it possible to capture these packets using a laptop using Wireshark?

Let me know, please.

Thanks

Akhilesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to capture these packets using a laptop using Wireshark?*

Yes, but your capture setup is almost certainly incorrect.  In a nutshell, you need to be able to capture packets in *monitor mode*, and you're not doing that.  Whether it's possible to do so using the WiFi card on your laptop is unknown, because not all cards support monitor mode on Windows.

Since it's impractical to provide an answer that simply repeats information already provided elsewhere, I'll refer you to the following sites for more detailed information:

- The Wireshark [WLAN (IEEE 802.11) capture setup](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup/WLAN#windows) wiki page
- Jasper Bongertz's blog about [Wireless Capture on Windows](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2019/04/wireless-capture-on-windows/)

See also my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893915/how-does-wireshark-capture-wlan-packets) question, which basically provides the same information.